# new files aren't existing after git push

Tags: git, linode

I have a problem: I have a git-repo on my linode which I've created with
    git init --bare project.git
within a folder so called "project".

After that I've cloned the repo and wanted to add some new files with 
    git add file.php" and "git commit -m "initial load"
and then: "git push origin master"

Everything works fine until here!

Now I am looking at my linode into the folder of the repo (project) and don't see any files I've pushed! I already had a look at git log where every commit is shown correctly. But where're my files???

Pls help :(

Comment: `--bare` creates a bare repository.  Why do you expect to see working files in a bare repository?

Comment: well, we're working with two people on this repository and for the other guy it works! I made it bare because of this tutorial: http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/

Comment: What do you mean by "it works" for the "other guy"?  If he does a push, are files appearing in the bare repo?  That is very unusual behavior!  If he pulls from the bare repo after you've done a push, the new files should be in his working repo.

Comment: yes he pushed files into the bare repo and they appeared! this is what makes me crazy...

Comment: Could it be that you clone project instead of the inner directory project.git?

Comment: no, I've cloned project.git

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've created a bare repo on your linode - it won't have a working copy, just the internal git representation. You can look at the log in that bare repo, but you won't see the files in the filesystem.

If elsewhere you clone the repo (a non-bare clone), it will have a working copy and you will see the files.  This clone will also have a copy of the internal git representation inside the .git directory at the root of the clone.

It is normal and advisable to [use a bare repo as your central coordination point](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/), because you should not push to a non-bare repo.

Answer (score 1):

Create a non-bare repository. Otherwise, you will only see git object/config files.